# Angularjs custom directive about how to control directive at controller or service?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to buid a directive that can be changed in controller or service at any time,for example,a bar at the top of window that I can change it whenever I want.Does any body know that?

Comment: You can have control on your directive's scope  in controller! what do you want exactly!?

Comment: Thank you,I've been solved it.